# I have a csv file from my energy provider

Tags: excel, csv

I have created a spreadsheet of a .csv file downloaded of my energy provider with usage per hour period per day. The sheet now has almost 7000 rows (a whole year would be 8760 or 8784). I would like to create a new column containing the total energy consumed between a user selectable time period for each day. The date increases after time point 23:00:00 to new date 00:00:00

This is a part of the file

```
    14-01-2015  03:00:00    0,0001968333333340
    14-01-2015  04:00:00    0,0001879000000000
    14-01-2015  05:00:00    0,0001856000000000
```

The 2 new columns should list the date and total usage.

p.e. between 03:00:00-05:00:00 equals

```
    14-10-2015    0,0005703333
```

The numbers should not be rounded off. I hope this can be done in Excel.

Comment: What exactly have you tried already? Remember that Stack Overflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: How do you propose to make the time period user selectable?

Comment: I love to find with an answer myself but have no idea where to start. Maybe I'll have to write code, so a little help to get forward is all I ask for. I used to write small programs in BASIC in the 80's, but haven't written a line of code since. 

I want a new sheet with 2 fields for start and end time and create a line chart with the resulting data. Usage shown vertical and date horizontally. With date labels showing the start of the month.

For a year I would get a graph with 365 or 366 data points. 

Hopefully this information will help someone to point me in a direction to go from there.

Answer (score 0):

With a PivotTable perhaps, where Time is filtered to select `03`, `04` and `05`:

[image: SO33320447 example]

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was really helpful.